# Drawing multiple line in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to draw lines in edittext. I have a scrollview inside which is editText.When number of lines in the editText is less then the total possible line that can be accommodated in view, I still want to draw the left lines after already drawn lines for text present in editText.

For example suppose if the no of lines in the edittext are 3 then only 3 lines are drawn .But I want to draw lines throughout the view in this case.

I've written below code but it is only drawing line upto height of text not beyond that.It will be a great help if anyone could help it .

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    final TextView textView_header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);

    final String randomText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Data");
    int index = Integer.parseInt(randomText);
    int pos = MainActivity.keyList.get(index);

    final String text = MainActivity.settings.getString("data" + pos, "");
    final String text_2 = MainActivity.settings_2.getString("data" + pos,
            "");

    textView_header.setText(text);

    LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editText_layout);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    LinedEditText et = new LinedEditText(this, null);

    et.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);

    et.setText(text_2);

    et.setKeyListener(null);

    et.setEnabled(false);

    et.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    et.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    sv.addView(et);

    ll.addView(sv);

}

public class LinedEditText extends EditText {

    private Rect mRect;

    private Paint mPaint;

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();

        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int height = getHeight();

        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();// for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);// first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1,
                    paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();// next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my xml layout for the activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/page2"
    tools:context="com.example.writenote.DisplayActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editText_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#a9a9a9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
        android:layout_marginRight="25px"
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="60px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="260px"
        android:layout_height="260px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circleedit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think the problem is in getHeight() which is in onDraw. It is returning height of editext which consists of three lines. Is there any way to provide the height of linearlayout which encloses edittext? I tried to provide height of linearlayout in onDraw method but there is no effect it's still drawing 3 lines.
I tried to do this in onDraw method

```
 //ll is linearLayout
 int height = ll.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the `ScrollView`, this ViewGroup is made to contain variable content size and add a scrollbar if this content is bigger than the provided space in the layout, thus you cannot use the `match_parent` configuration inside a `ScrollView` (your `EditText` will automatically be set to `wrap_content` on its height).

You simply have to call `sv.fillViewPort(true);` in your `onCreate` to stretch the content if smaller than the `ScrollView` height, as stated in [the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setFillViewport%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText"
 android:width="wrap_content"
 android:height="wrap_content"
 android:maxLines="2"/>
```

maxLines number is your required lines count;

you want multiple lines in edit text ....set edit text width is fixed and height is warap_content then it automaticall enter new line....